# breadth first search for characters instead of integers c++

Tags: c++, string, stack, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to create a menu driven program to produce a depth first search and breadth first search for a graph. I was able to get it to work for integers but I need it to do the same for characters or strings instead of integers.

I keep getting a error zsh:segmentation fault whenever any option is selected.

Any help is appreciated
This is the code below:

```
#include "stdc++.h"
using namespace std;


void DFS();
//void minimumPath();
//void invalid();

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node* link;
};
 
struct Node* top;
 
void push(char data)
{
     
    // Create new node temp and allocate memory
    struct Node* temp;
    temp = new Node();
 
    // Check if stack (heap) is full.
    // Then inserting an element would
    // lead to stack overflow
    if (!temp)
    {
        cout << "\nHeap Overflow";
        exit(1);
    }
 
    // Initialize data into temp data field
    temp->data = data;
 
    // Put top pointer reference into temp link
    temp->link = top;
 
    // Make temp as top of Stack
    top = temp;
}
 
// Utility function to check if
// the stack is empty or not
char isEmpty()
{
    return top == NULL;
}
 
// Utility function to return top element in a stack
char peek()
{
     
    // Check for empty stack
    if (!isEmpty())
        return top->data;
    else
        exit(1);
}
 
// Utility function to pop top
// element from the stack
void pop()
{
    struct Node* temp;
 
    // Check for stack underflow
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nStack Underflow" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
         
        // Top assign into temp
        temp = top;
 
        // Assign second node to top
        top = top->link;
 
        // Destroy connection between
        // first and second
        temp->link = NULL;
 
        // Release memory of top node
        free(temp);
    }
}
 


// This class represents a directed graph using adjacency
// list representation
class Graph
{
int V; // No. of vertices
list<char> *adj; // adjacency lists
public:
Graph(int V); // Constructor
void addEdge(char v, char w); // to add an edge to graph
void DFS(char s); // prints all vertices in DFS manner
// from a given source.
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
this->V = V;
adj = new list<char>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(char v, char w)
{
adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
}

// prints all not yet visited vertices reachable from s
void Graph::DFS(char s)
{
// Initially mark all vertices as not visited
vector<bool> visited(V, false);

// // Create a stack for DFS
// stack<int> stack;

// Push the current source node.
push(s);

while (!isEmpty())
{
// Pop a vertex from stack and print it
char s = peek();
pop();

// Stack may contain same vertex twice. So
// we need to print the popped item only
// if it is not visited.
if (!visited[s])
{
cout << s << " ";
visited[s] = true;
}

// Get all adjacent vertices of the popped vertex s
// If a adjacent has not been visited, then push it
// to the stack.
for (auto i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); ++i)
if (!visited[*i])
push(*i);


    }
   
}


void addEdgee(vector<char> adj[], char src, char dest)
{
    adj[src].push_back(dest);
    adj[dest].push_back(src);
}
 
// a modified version of BFS that stores predecessor
// of each vertex in array p
// and its distance from source in array d
bool BFS(vector<char> adj[], char src, char dest, int v,
         char pred[], char dist[])
{
    // a queue to maintain queue of vertices whose
    // adjacency list is to be scanned as per normal
    // DFS algorithm
    list<char> queue;
 
    // boolean array visited[] which stores the
    // information whether ith vertex is reached
    // at least once in the Breadth first search
    bool visited[v];
 
    // initially all vertices are unvisited
    // so v[i] for all i is false
    // and as no path is yet constructed
    // dist[i] for all i set to infinity
    for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
        dist[i] = INT_MAX;
        pred[i] = -1;
    }
 
    // now source is first to be visited and
    // distance from source to itself should be 0
    visited[src] = true;
    dist[src] = 0;
    queue.push_back(src);
 
    // standard BFS algorithm
    while (!queue.empty()) {
        int u = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();
        for (int i = 0; i < adj[u].size(); i++) {
            if (visited[adj[u][i]] == false) {
                visited[adj[u][i]] = true;
                dist[adj[u][i]] = dist[u] + 1;
                pred[adj[u][i]] = u;
                queue.push_back(adj[u][i]);
 
                // We stop BFS when we find
                // destination.
                if (adj[u][i] == dest)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
 
    return false;
}
 
// utility function to print the shortest distance
// between source vertex and destination vertex
void minimumPath(vector<char> adj[], char s,
                           char dest, int v)
{
    // predecessor[i] array stores predecessor of
    // i and distance array stores distance of i
    // from s
    char pred[v], dist[v];
 
    if (BFS(adj, s, dest, v, pred, dist) == false) {
        cout << "Given source and destination"
             << " are not connected";
        return;
    }
 
    // vector path stores the shortest path
    vector<char> path;
    char crawl = dest;
    path.push_back(crawl);
    while (pred[crawl] != -1) {
        path.push_back(pred[crawl]);
        crawl = pred[crawl];
    }
 
    // printing path from source to destination
    for (int i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << path[i] << " ";
}


// Main definition  
int main()
{
    int choice;
    while (1) {

        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t      M E N U \n";
        cout << "Depth-First Search (0), Minimum Path Search (1)\n";
        cout << "Exit Program (3) \n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t Choose? ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 0) {
            Graph g(9);
            g.addEdge('A', 'B');
            g.addEdge('A', 'C');
            g.addEdge('A', 'D');
            g.addEdge('B', 'B');
            g.addEdge('C', 'G');
            g.addEdge('D', 'C');
            g.addEdge('D', 'G');
            g.addEdge('E', 'C');
            g.addEdge('E', 'F');
            g.addEdge('F', 'C');
            g.addEdge('F', 'H');
            g.addEdge('G', 'F');
            g.addEdge('G', 'H');
            g.addEdge('G', 'I');
            g.addEdge('H', 'E');
            g.addEdge('H', 'I');
            g.addEdge('I', 'F');
            char data;
            cin >> data;
            g.DFS(data);
        }
        else if (choice == 1) {
            int v = 9;
            vector<char> adj[v];
           
            addEdgee(adj,'A', 'B');
            addEdgee(adj,'A', 'C');
            addEdgee(adj,'A', 'D');
            addEdgee(adj,'B', 'B');
            addEdgee(adj,'C', 'G');
            addEdgee(adj,'D', 'C');
            addEdgee(adj,'D', 'G');
            addEdgee(adj,'E', 'C');
            addEdgee(adj,'E', 'F');
            addEdgee(adj,'F', 'C');
            addEdgee(adj,'F', 'H');
            addEdgee(adj,'G', 'F');
            addEdgee(adj,'G', 'H');
            addEdgee(adj,'G', 'I');
            addEdgee(adj,'H', 'E');
            addEdgee(adj,'H', 'I');
            addEdgee(adj,'I', 'F');
           
            char K,L;
            cin >> K >> L;
            minimumPath(adj, K, L, v);
        }

        else if (choice == 3) {
            exit(0);
        }
       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. did you try using breakpoint to find culprit line of code?

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to ask people to wade through. As a debugging tip: if the code works fine with `int` but doesn't work with `char`, then there's probably a; mistake in rewriting it to use `char`. So go back to the `int` code, write `typedef int my_type;` at the top, and change all the `int` data to `my_type`. Get that working again, and then change the typedef to `typedef char my_type;`.

Comment: @VivekMangal No I haven't but thank you, I will try that now.